# how to return duplicate value index if it contains another array of object inside array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var someArray = [
    { 
    id: 1, 
    description: 'xyz',
    assignedValue: [{code : 1 , description:'aaa'},{code : 2 , description:'ddd'},{code : 3 , description:'fff'}]
    },
    { 
    id: 2, 
    description: 'txy',
    assignedValue: [{code : 5 , description:'aaa'},{code : 2 , description:'ddd'},{code : 6 , description:'fff'}] 
    }    
  ];
```

code 2 is duplicated in the assignedValue array of object, need the index of the object which contains the duplicate value

Comment: Please format your question in an understandable way. What is your expected output?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you are trying to do and what the expected the result is.

Comment: need the index of the object which contains duplicate value.

Comment: The index for each object? What is the expected result?

Comment: @hev1 we can find  {code : 2 , description:'ddd'} in first object and the second object too.

I need to find the index of the first duplicate object